# Duvida com conditions no cakephp?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2

Estou tentando fazer um `conditions` em um `find`. Tenho 2 tabelas: `tipopessoas` e `pessoas`, na tabela `pessoas` tenho uma chave estrangeira para tabela `tipopessoas`. Quero que meu find traga o resultado apenas para dois tipos de pessoas, `RESPONSAVEL` e `PROFESSOR`, pra isso estou tentando usar um find com `conditions` usando `OR`, porem apenas um resultado retorna.

Como fazer para que retorne os 2 tipos de pessoas e nao apenas 1 ?

Estou tentando assim.

```
$this->set("pessoas", $this->User->Pessoa->find('list', array(
                                                        'fields' => array("Pessoa.id", "Pessoa.nome", "Pessoa.tipopessoas_id",'Tipopessoa.id','Tipopessoa.descricao'),
                                                        "conditions"=>array("OR"=>array('Tipopessoa.descricao = '=>'RESPONSAVEL', 
                                                                                        'Tipopessoa.descricao = '=>'PROFESSOR')),
                                                        'recursive' => 0)));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boas, estás quase lá. O que tens de fazer é algo do genero:

```
"conditions"=>array("OR"=>array(
    array('Tipopessoa.descricao' =>'RESPONSAVEL'),
    array('Tipopessoa.descricao' =>'PROFESSOR') )
 )
```

outro método que poderás utilizar é:

```
"conditions"=> array('Tipopessoa.descricao' => array('RESPONSAVEL', 'PROFESSOR'));
```

Comment: perfeito, muito obrigado !